# How to refresh captcha code without refreshing the page

Tags: php, javascript, html

When I click on my given refresh link, my captcha code refreshes only once. If I again click on the refresh link it doesn't refresh the captcha code. I don't understand why that is happening.

This is my code:

```
<a href='javascript: refresh_captcha();'>refresh</a>  
function refresh_captcha()
{
    <?php
        $captcha1 = new CaptchaCode();
        $code = str_encrypt($captcha1->generateCode(6));

    ?>
    var img = document.getElementById('captcha_img');
    img.src = '<?php echo "/captcha_images.php?width=120&height=40&code=$code"?>';
    document.getElementById ("captcha_img").src = img.src;

}
```

Comment: you need to learn the difference between server side code (PHP) and client side code (Javascript), PHP only runs once while building the page, if you want to trigger some PHP code after that yo need a new HTTP request, if you don't want a page refresh then you may want to look into using AJAX

Comment: can u provide me the solution?? i want this without refreshing page

Comment: Show clear code @user2746093

Comment: @user2746093 Try and understand what the previous commenter is saying. Your `refresh_captcha` function is written by PHP **once**, and the end result is a function that looks like this: http://jsfiddle.net/MS3jy/. Notice that the code being inserted for the `code` querystring parameter is static as far as JS is concerned. If you want to have PHP evaluate something and send it to the page without reloading it entirely, you need to use AJAX.

Comment: You can get code variable value by javascript with AJAX. I have given example how to get code variable value by javascript.

Comment: this was helpful in my case , http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/image-reload.php

Answer (score 2):

here is my approach

```
 <p>
      <img id='captcha_img' style='border: 1px solid #CBD8E5;' src='/captcha.php?img=<?=time();?>'/><br/>

      <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('captcha_img').src='captcha.php?img=' + Math.random(); return false">Reload Captcha</a>
 </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try replacing your function with javascript ajax call

```
function refresh_captcha()
{
    $.ajax({
    type:"GET"
    url: "/captcha_images.php?width=120&height=40&code=$code"?>'
    success: function(msg)
   {
    document.getElementById ("captcha_img").src = msg;
   },
error:functon(){alert("some error occured");}
     });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below code

```
<a href='javascript: refresh_captcha();'>refresh</a>  
    function randomString(length, chars) {
        var result = '';
        for (var i = length; i > 0; --i) result += chars[Math.round(Math.random() * (chars.length - 1))];
        return result;
    }
    function refresh_captcha()
    {
        var code = randomString(6, '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
        var img = document.getElementById('captcha_img');
        img.src = '<?php echo "/captcha_images.php?width=120&height=40&code="?>'+code;
        document.getElementById ("captcha_img").src = img.src;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

do u know how php page is evaluated on server.

means:

when a php page is parsed on server , then php code is evaluated and and evaluated result is send back to page .then page is sent to browser.my mean to say, you will have only static content as html javascript, css on your browser.if you want to evaluate your php code then you have to send a request to server.

It can be sent in two ways.

1. By Page reloading
2. By AJAX.

so if you don't want to reload you page then you should go for ajax.
then you code will be

```
<a href='javascript: refresh_captcha();'>refresh</a>  
function refresh_captcha()
{
 // ajax call to server to get new captcha string
 // evaluate this code on server and send string back to browser
 //<?php
 //   $captcha1 = new CaptchaCode();
 //   $code = str_encrypt($captcha1->generateCode(6));
 //
 //?>
 // var code = <ajax response>

var img = document.getElementById('captcha_img');
img.src = '/captcha_images.php?width=120&height=40&code='+code; // change this line
//document.getElementById ("captcha_img").src = img.src;

}
```

for ajax call read this
http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/

Comment: `document.getElementById("captcha_img").src = img.src;` is redundant. `img` **is** the result of `document.getElementById("captcha_img")`.